# Batch files: why should I ever use normal expansion instead of delayed expansion?

Tags: variables, batch-file

I understand what normal expansion and delayed expansion means. But delayed expansion works just like variables in 'normal' programming languages such as C and Java, while normal expansion is plain annoying and weird.

Two questions:

1. What should I favor 'by default': normal expansion (i.e. `%var%`) or delayed expansion (i.e. `!var!`)? It seems to me favoring `!var!` by default is a good idea, but most places you see `%var%` being used by default.
2. If `!var!` should be preferred, when should I use `%var%`?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not doing any research into previous questions before posting a new one here? You're asking for a tutorial on batch programming, and there are dozens of prior questions here dealing with variable expansion (both normal and delayed) that demonstrate the difference quite clearly between them. I'm asking because this is the second question today within a short period of time you've posted asking about the same basic information, which to me indicates a lack of research effort before posting. SO should be the *last resort* after you've exhausted other options.

Comment: For instance, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21183602), which clearly shows the difference between the two, and when each should be used. If I can find it in 5 minutes, and I wasn't looking for it, it seems strange that your research here didn't turn it up.

Comment: The answers to the question you posted don't answer mine. I understand what delayed and normal expansion are, how they work and what each one does. Because I do, I don't see an advantage to `%var%`, and this is why I posted this question.

Comment: `%var%` is normal expansion, which means it happens when the line is first encountered. It's necessary most of the time. `!var!` delays the expansion until the line actually executes, which is necessary if you're changing the value of `var` (for instance in a `for` loop) after it's been loaded the first time. The question I linked explains how delayed expansion is used, and the answers provide a fairly clear demonstration of the differences between them. (It's also only one of hundreds of posts available here related to the topic. I'm asking why you haven't spent some time researching.)

Comment: As far as when you should use each: Clearly, you use **normal** expansion under **normal** circumstances, and use **delayed** expansion when **normal** expansion isn't possible (like when the value needs to be changed within a `for` loop). Use *normal* until you find a condition where *normal* doesn't work, and then you use the *not normal* delayed expansion.

Comment: I think, his question is: Why should I use %var%, if !var! seems to work in "normal" AND "non-normal" situations.

Comment: @Stephan That is pretty much my question. And also I don't understand why everybody seems to use `%var%` as the default while `!var!` is much more 'normal' and intuitive.

Comment: I was one of "everybody" until I read your question. Now I doubt... I'm afraid, I will spend some hours on the computer this weekend ;(

Comment: @AvivCohn did you ever solve this question?

Comment: This is an example that only works with %normal% expansion; this means that it is _not_ possible to do this in any other programming language this way. The purpose is to exchange the values of two variables: `set "var1=%var2%" & set "var2=%var1%"`

Answer (score 0):

When you use `!var!` then `!` becomes another poison character.