# Writing a For Loop in Batch Scripting

Tags: batch-file

I'm currently stuck on an assignment for my OS class dealing with batch scripting. The main issue I'm having is writing a functional for loop in the program that accurately goes through a range from 1 to 100 and calculates the sum via the arithmetic expression %%variable mod 5 + 3.

The current results I've been getting ranges from either getting just a 0 as an answer when running, or numbers which increment by 3, for example, 3 then 6 then 9 etc.

Here is the appropriate section of my code:

```
for /l %%i in (1, 1, 100) do (
set /a result = %%i %% 5
set /a calctotal = %result% + 3
)
set /a average = %calctotal%/100
echo %average%
pause
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Batch file processing - Loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183602/windows-batch-file-processing-loops)

Comment: @SomethingDark: I've seen this very problem before - a few days ago - with the same poorly-expressed calculation. Regrettably, your nominated "duplicate" is IMHO overly complex for a beginner - the `;` are unnecessary for instance - and you actually don't need delayedexpansion (in this instance.)

Comment: @Magoo - `%calctotal%` is being initialized inside of a code block; how do you _not_ need delayed expansion?

Comment: @SomethingDark : read my solution & try it! The `set /a` syntax works on the `run-time` value, not the `parse-time` value...

Answer (score 1):

```dos
SET /a calctotal=0
for /l %%i in (1, 1, 100) do (
 set /a result = %%i %% 5
 set /a calctotal += result + 3
)
set /a average = %calctotal%/100
echo %average%
```

The problem to me is the interpretation of "calculate the sum via the arithmetic expression %%variable mod 5 + 3"

Now does this mean `the sum of (%%variable mod 5 + 3)` or `(the sum of (%%variable) mod 5 + 3` ??

Anyhow, there are some problems with your code (well, if there wasn't, you'd not be asking, would you?)

First, in a 'block' (parenthesised series of lines) any `%var%` is replaced by the value of `var` at the time the block was encountered, and does not change as the block is executed. The classic way to deal with this is to invoke `delayedexpansion`.

Hence, in your code, you were executing `set /a calctotal = + 3` 100 times, as `%result%` would have been replaced by its value at the start of the loop (presumably undefined, hence *nothing*)

Next problem is that you are attempting to set `calctotal` to the latest value of `result` - you are not **accumulating** the values.

**however** in this case, you can use the `set /a` syntax, which works on the `current` value of the variables - provided you don't invoke them as `%var%`.

`set /a calctotal += result + 3` uses `+=` to accumulate the values. You could also use `set /a calctotal = calctotal + result + 3` which may be more obvious.

I set `calctotal` to zero before starting just in case it's aready set.

And no doubt you could remove the need for `result` by using `set /a calctotal += %%i %% 5 + 3`